# How to set OnclickListener for the dynamically added items in recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, checkedtextview

In my application I'm using a recycler view to show some data and for each item in recyclerview I'm adding a list of checked text view. These checked textviews are added according to the size of list provided and it works fine. Now I want to add the click listener for those items to know if they are checked or not?

When items are checked those checked items should be taken to another activity. But now the click listener is added directly in recycler view which won't access me to do out of box code. So I'm looking for how to add a click listener and access it in another activity.

My Recyclerview code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.allio.customer.R;
import com.allio.customer.models.Types_Item;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionLayout;
import com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.viewgroup.ExpansionLayoutCollection;

public class Types_adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Types_Item, Types_adapter.RecyclerHolder> {

    private final ExpansionLayoutCollection expansionsCollection = new ExpansionLayoutCollection();
    Context context;

    public Types_adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Types_Item> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        expansionsCollection.openOnlyOne(true);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Types_Item model) {
        expansionsCollection.add(holder.getExpansionLayout());
        holder.textView.setText(model.getName());
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(model.getImageURL())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        CheckedTextView[] textView = new CheckedTextView[model.getProblems().size()];
        holder.problems.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getProblems().size(); i++){
            textView[i] = new CheckedTextView(context);
            textView[i].setText(model.getProblems().get(i));
            textView[i].setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            textView[i].setTextSize(15);
            int finalI = i;
            textView[i].setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (textView[finalI].isChecked()){
                    textView[finalI].setChecked(false);
                    textView[finalI].setCheckMarkDrawable(0);
                }else {
                    textView[finalI].setChecked(true);
                    textView[finalI].setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.checked);
                }
            });
            holder.problems.addView(textView[i]);
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return RecyclerHolder.buildFor(parent);
    }

    public final static class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.item_types;

        ExpansionLayout expansionLayout;
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        LinearLayout problems;

        public static RecyclerHolder buildFor(ViewGroup viewGroup){
            return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(LAYOUT, viewGroup, false));
        }

        public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            expansionLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expansionLayout);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_image);
            problems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.problems_list);
        }

        public ExpansionLayout getExpansionLayout() {
            return expansionLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CheckedTextView[] textView;` Make that a class variable. If you need the data use a for loop and textView[i].isChecked() to get the status.

Comment: `i want to get the list of selected items ` ? You want the list of checked items?

Comment: @blackapps sorry for replying late. In my case when an item from the list is selected then a child layout is shown and a number is displayed according to the no. of items selected from the list if no item is selected then the child layout goes hidden. And when checked these list of selected items will be taken to another activity. I'm looking for a proper approach of how to know the state of checked textview and write code accordingly.

Comment: @blackapps wish i'll get a solution as i'm struggling with this from past week. This only solution helps me to complete my app.

Comment: I told you all in my first comment. What do you need more?

Comment: how to know whether the item is checked or not outside of recyclerview

Comment: You can read all in my first comment. You can even place array variable in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an interface class and bind this interface into constructor of adapter class.

```
public interface CustomDialogListener {
    void onItemClicked(CheckedTextView checkedTextView);
}
```

this is for adapter class

```
private CustomDialogListener mViewClickListener;
public ProductsAdapter(Context context,boolean status) {
    this.context = context;
    this.status = status;
    this.mViewClickListener = (CustomDialogListener) context;
}
```

and assign interface class method on your required action like onClick on any view.

```
 textView[i].setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (textView[finalI].isChecked()){
                textView[finalI].setChecked(false);
                textView[finalI].setCheckMarkDrawable(0);
            }else {
                textView[finalI].setChecked(true);
                textView[finalI].setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.checked);
            }
            listener.onItemClicked(textView);
        });
```

add implementation of interface in parent activity class and override the interface method.

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
YourAdapter.CustomDialogListener {
  
  @Override
  public void onItemClicked(CheckedTextView checkedTextView) {
    //Log.d("Item clicked", checkedTextView.isChecked()+"");
  }
}
```

thats the way to track event of recyclerView.
hope i made myself clear.

Comment: I'll try and check if you're solution helps me.

Comment: listener.onItemClicked(textView); replace this with
listener.onItemClicked(textView[i]); // should be instance of CheckedTextView

Comment: happy to help you.